# Trouble Ripping CDs

Tags: cd, sound-juicer

I am trying to rip some CDs (Persona 5 soundtrack, if that matters) and I am having some trouble. This is an actual retail copy of the soundtrack, not a copy of a copy.

Disc 1 rips just fine.

In Sound Juicer, for discs 2 and 3, about 2/3s through both discs I receive this error: "Sound Juicer could not extract this CD. Reason: Could not open resource for writing." I am not sure why this error occurs, because my computer is not going to sleep, the CD drive is still active, and the destination hard drive still has space. All tracks on the CDs also play in whatever media player I use. Any ideas?

If I use Rhythm Box to rip the CDs, the CDs rip but the meta-data is all messed up. There is no album art, and for example tracks may be written as 11 minutes long but they are really only 4 or 5 minutes long.

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Try asunder. I've had similar problems. SoundJuicer had always problems with multiple CDs. My last CD I ripped with asunder without problems

Comment: Will try Asunder next time. Figured out the problem- I am dumb. Solution written below. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUTION:** It was a problem with the destination hard drive. That's why it's fine until the middle of the rip- looks like the hard drive can maintain a connection for writing only for a period of time, and Disc 1 is shorter than the others, that's why it rips without problem. I figured this out when the hard drive kept disappearing from my file navigator. Once I changed the destination hard drive everything was fine. Now need to troubleshoot the first hard drive... Hopefully it's just a faulty SATA cable...

Comment: Indeed a strange error, glad you've found it